# Valid un-stamped Dutch tourist visa, do I need Airport Transit Visa (ATV) for France? - Pakistan Passport

Tags: schengen, france, transit-visas, air-france, schengen-visas

So I already have a valid Schengen tourist visa issued from Dutch embassy on my valid Pakistan passport. However, I have not yet traveled on it to Holland so it is still un-stamped by the immigration in Holland.

Now I have to make a trip to US through Air France (tickets purchased). Since I will be transiting through Paris CDG, will I need to apply for a separate Airport Transit Visa for Paris,France?

My understanding is that a new Schengen tourist visa is not issued (from other Schengen nation) as long as there is a valid Schengen tourist visa from another state. 
Is this also applicable in case of Transit Visa?

Comment: Your valid Schengen visa exempts you from the requirement for an airport transit visa.  This is true even if the valid Schengen visa is unused.  You may be asked why the valid Schengen visa was unused, so you should be prepared to answer that question (truthfully!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an airport transit visa. Article 3(5) of the Schengen Visa code provides that

> The following categories of persons shall be exempt from the requirement to hold an airport transit visa provided for in paragraphs 1 and 2:
>
> (a) holders of a valid uniform visa, national long-stay visa or residence permit issued by a Member State;

The slightly confusing thing is that under some conditions, actually *entering* France on this visa could be problematic but you are not doing that. If your visa is valid, you're exempt from the other requirement, period. There is no ambiguity about that and you won't be crossing an external border, where all the other rules become relevant.

Additionally, note that any US visa you may have (as you probably need one to enter the US) would also exempt you from the airport transit visa requirement.

Comment: Yes that is correct and as you mentioned I won't be leaving any external borders. My only concern was that my dutch schengen visa still being un-used. Then again as long as it's valid, I should be exempt.